# Call running program and get response in php

Tags: php, c++, daemon

I've created a c++ program which requires user input. I want to call this program from php and use the output of the program on my webpage. 
Since the c++ program takes a lot of time to initialize I want to keep it running in the background and respond to the php script when called. The php script should then get the output and display it on my page. 
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it can be done, but you'll probably have to write two C or C++ programs, one that runs in the background, and one that is started by your PHP program for each time you need some info. Although it may be possible to come up with a scheme using only PHP - I haven't looked into it very much. Either way, I will use the term "requester" for the processs (PHP or C) that "asks for the information", and "service process" for the process that actually responds with information.

To communicate between the requester and the background process, you will need to use some IPC (Interprocess Communication) mechanism. There are a number of choices. A named pipe sounds like a reasonable solution in this case, and named pipes are available in most OS's (as well as abstracted in for example Boost libraries, to allow a more portable solution, if that is required).

So, the basic principle is:

1. Background service process is started (automatically at system start).
2. Service process creates named pipe (in bidirectional mode, or two pipes, one for each direction - I'm using a single pipe below - adjust for "input pipe" and "output pipe" as required)
3. When required, requester process opens the named pipe and sends a request message.
4. Service process sends message back with information requested.
5. Requester closes pipe.
6. Repeat steps 2-5 as required.
7. Background process shuts down, and as part of that destroys the named pipe (automatically at system shut down).

There is of course many "small steps" for each of those 7 steps above, but in general, it's pretty much what you'd want to do.

Comment: Thanks! I've looked a bit into IPC mechanisms and I think I'll give shared memory a try. The program initializes about 600mb of memory and reading that from a named pipe would probably be too slow.

Comment: But surely, you don't deliver 600MB of data EVERY time you request from your C++ program, but only the data actually requested by the client? And as long as the data is in memory (which it should be if you have enough RAM in your server and don't load too many other things). Shared memory is more difficult to use, since you need to deal with read/write issues (e.g. service program updates the data while you are reading it in the client)

Comment: I think you're right. I thought I needed all the data, but I'll just need the background process to handle the request which requires all the data and then share the resulting data.

Comment: Indeed, that's how most of these things work - and I believe for instance MySQL uses a named pipe to achieve this (also, if you ever need multiple clients [more than one web session at any given time], it gets even messier if you use shared memory - unless the shared memory is simply a constant lump of data that never changes).